# How to Start activiti workflow using rest api?

Tags: activiti, workflow-activity

I create an activiti workflow. I want to start workflow using rest api. Please give some solution for the same. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Activiti REST-API Reference: http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#_start_a_process_instance

If you want to start a process instance, you can use `POST runtime/process-instances`

Comment: For me, this rest call always shows the 6 processes and not any other process. Even though I can run my workflow in standalone activiti UI. Any idea what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

this is the the link start a workflow through rest-api:P
http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/runtime/process-instances

and  pass your query with this link like this......
{"processDefinitionKey":"your workflow id","variables":[{"value":"your form data value","name":"form data id"}]}

Comment: For me, this rest call always shows the 6 processes and not any other process. Even though I can run my workflow in standalone activiti UI. Any idea what is the problem